# install grub but no booting

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, mbr

I'm having trouble installing grub.

I used to have a UEFI boot setup but it constantly failed so I decided to use normal boot instead. Unfortunately, the system doesnt boot into grub.

What I did was:

1. Disabled UEFI by choosing `legacy oprom only` in the BIOS settings.
2. Create a ef02 partition in `/dev/sda3`.
3. Install grub like this:

-

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdx
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

But nothing is booting except my arch-linux from a USB.

My motherboard is Asus 7 Maximus.

Maybe someone can help me solving this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your bios is attempting to boot the USB drive first. Check your boot order in BIOS.